# Correct visualization of a probability density function of 3 continuous random variables

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, visualization

I am reading Rice's book of mathematical statistics, and I have understood that if we visualize a joint probability density function (pdf) of 2 continuous random variables, then in 3D space they define a plane of course, but the pdf itself, or in other words the probability that the 2 random variables fall within a region for the joint pdf, is essentially a volume, since the pdf is defined on the third axis:

[image: Image taken from: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Illustration-of-a-bivariate-Gaussian-distribution-The-marginal-and-joint-probability_fig1_320182941]

So this is a volume in 3D space.

My question is what happens in a multivariate probability density function of **3** continuous random variables. How can we visualize that? Is the probability that the 3 random variables fall within a region still a volume in 3D space? Or is it 4D space?

Comment: If you had a physical 3D object that was a particular shape made of varying material so with varying density, you would not regard it a 4D object, but you might still consider its total mass, or the position of its centre of mass, or the proportion of the total mass mass represented by a particular part of it.